# Converting a MKV file with DTS MA audio to AC3 5.1 (With no loss in video)

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska, ac3

I have a linux server on which i need to do this.  I have a video MKV video file with AVC video and DTS MA audio, i need to convert this to a file with AC3 5.1 Audio with no loss in video and as little a loss as possible in audio. 
I've tried using ffmpeg tool, but cant seem to get the settings right. Any ideas?

Comment: Show your `ffmpeg` command and the complete log.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple actually.

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mkv -c:v copy -c:a ac3 outputfile.mkv
```

This will copy the video track lossless and convert the audio track to ac3 while combining into a new .mkv file. This is assuming the DTS audio track is also multichannel 5.1. I believe it will auto merge the side channels into 5.1, if the source DTS is 7.1.